# Casting in defining attributes of a Class?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm a Python newbie and I'm dealing with Object Programming. 
Studying my teacher code, I've found something strange at `self.items = list(items)`. 
Look at the overall code:

```
class Truck():  
    '''
    This class models a truck
    '''
    def __init__(self, plate_number, capacity, items):
        '''
        Constructor of an object of class Truck
        :param plate_number: a unique number Identifying the truck
        :param capacity: maximum weight that the truck can carry
        :param items: list of objects of class Item carried by the truck
        '''
        self.plate_number = plate_number
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.items = list(items)
```

So, why should I cast the parameter `items`, whereas the other parameters don't need this operation?

Comment: You are converting items, which should be a sequence and turning it into a list. Check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_list.htm

Comment: That depends on what the received `items` argument is. Maybe it's a tuple and then you need to cast it to a list so that it can be mutated. Can you check what's passed to the function? Also, you have an indentation problem.

Comment: The intent looks to be primarily a defensive copy; the type conversion effect is secondary, considering that the docstring requires `items` to already be a list.

Comment: My teacher said that what I've called "casting" (at this point, I'm not sure it's a cast) is for creating a copy, so that the item list passed as parameter can not be modified. I don't know why this operation is necessary for the list of item and not for the other parameter. Thanks nir0s for noticing about bad indentation: I've fixed it,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other parameters (`plate_number` and `capacity`) are probably immutable (a string and an int presumably). However `items` is a list (if we are to trust the docstring) which is mutable.

Using it as it is in `Truck`'s `__init__` would have resulted in changes made to `truck_obj.items` affecting the original passed `items` list as well (and vice-versa).

Calling `list(items)` results in a newly created list being assigned to `self.items`. This can also be achieved by using slicing syntax: `self.items = items[:]`.

Compare:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items


li = [1, 2]

obj = A(li)
li[0] = 9
print(obj.items)
#  [9, 2]  oops! we modified obj.items without intending to
```

to

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = list(items)  # or items[:]


li = [1, 2]

obj = A(li)
li[0] = 9
print(obj.items)
#  [1, 2]
```

Comment: Assuming that we're expecting a list to be passed into the constructor, you could also use the `copy` module to create a new list, alternatively allowing for a `deep copy` as well. Though subjective, I'd be inclined that since the OP discusses casting, the assumed intention of the instructor was not for copying, but rather to force a type on several possible collection inputs, while copying is a side-effect.

Comment: @DeepSpace, your code is very explaining, but I have not understood the following statement:
"Using it as it is in Truck's __init__ would have resulted in changes made to truck_obj.items affecting the original passed items list as well (and vice-versa)."
Why list li in your code has changed?

Comment: @Bernheart Because in the first case `li` and `obj.items` are the exact same list. You can visualize this by printing `id(li)` and `id(obj.items)`.

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai: The questioner mentions casting, but the questioner didn't write the code and isn't an authoritative source on the code author's intent. The docstring makes it clear that the parameter should be a list, so no type conversion is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor is saying "I can only work with `items` in the class, if they're in a `list`". What this roughly translates to is, "The `items` attribute  of class `Truck` must be an ordered, indexed, and mutable collection".

For example, there is a chance that someone passes in a `tuple` for `items`, and if for example, you needed to add or remove items in the `Truck` class, you can't add or remove items from a `tuple` (but you can with a `list`).

Casting to a `list` is explicit, and should it not raise an error, is guaranteed to be a list regardless of what gets passed into `items`. This is a part of what we call "pythonic".

EDIT: To piggy back off of a very good point by DeepSpace, casting to `list` also creates a shallow copy of the list to manipulate, as opposed to the list itself.

Comment: My teacher talked about copies, I think you are right in your EDIT

Answer (score 0):

In this example your teacher is assuming that `plate_number` and `capacity` are two immutable variables and `items` should be represented as a `list`.

So, when passing variables in `__init__()` method your `items` variables must be an `iterable` and can be represented as a `list`.

You can see this example with a `generator`:

```
class Truck():
    def __init__(self, plate_number, capacity, items):
        self.plate_number = plate_number
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.items = list(items)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "plate_number: %r\ncapacity: %r\nitems: %r" % (self.plate_number, self.capacity, self.items)


# Test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = 12
    capacity = 13
    # Generator wich can be represented as a list
    items = (k for k in [1,2,3,4])
    app = Truck(number, capacity, items)
    print(app)
    # OR
    #print(repr(app))
```

Output:

```
plate_number: 12
capacity: 13
items: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```